# Linux kernel module programming Makefile

Tags: makefile, kernel

I'm trying to create a helloworld module. I have to write a makefile as below.

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE), )
obj-m := hello.o
else
KDIR := /path/to/kernel/sources
all:
    make -C  $(KDIR) M= 'pwd' modules
endif
```

I came to know that this makefile runs twice. How does it run twice by invoking only once?

When is the `obj-m` value used here?

Comment: I have edited (it's waiting for peer review) to clean up the file contents formatting.  Please review and make certain it looks like the original file (including the tab (not spaces)) before the call to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makefile has a single rule:

```
all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M= 'pwd' modules
```

In English: "go to the directory `$(KDIR)` and execute Make (the target is `modules`)".

So when *you* invoke Make using this makefile, *it* invokes Make using another makefile.

You should start with something simpler. We can help, if you tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea. But, the second time, it would invoke a different makefile (top-level makefile).  Then when is the obj-m in this makefile get executed?

Comment: @Gomathi: in the makefile *as shown*, either `$(KERNELRELEASE)` is empty, in which case `obj-m` is never set or mentioned, or `$(KERNELRELEASE)` is *not* empty, in which case obj-m is set but never used (and there is no rule, so Make will complain and quit).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this file *might* have one rule, but only if `KERNELRELEASE` is empty.  `obj-m` only gets defined if `KERNELRELEASE` is *not* empty, in which case the `Makefile` won't really do anything...  I'm guessing that `obj-m` will be used by the kernel including this `Makefile` (after having defined `KERNELRELEASE`) in one of it's own in case you were actually building it into the kernel rather than as a dynamically loaded module.